# Two questions about convolution

Tags: lp-spaces, convolution, smooth-functions

Good day to everyone, I have the following two questions about convolutions of smooth functions with compact suppport ($C_c^k(\mathbb{R}^d)$ or $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R^d})$).

1. If $f$ from $C_c^m(\mathbb{R}^d))$ and $g$ from $C_c^n(\mathbb{R^d})$, what can we say about $f*g$? I am quite sure that $f*g\in C_c^{\max (m,n)}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, but can it be more than this? Can it be that always $f*g\in C_c^ {m+n}(\mathbb{R}^d)$?
2. Is the set $\{f*g: f,g \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d) \}$ dense in $L^1$? I suppose so but not sure.
   Thanks for Your help.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For your second question: yes. This can be shown by taking $f = \delta^{-d} \phi(x/\delta)$ where $\int \phi dx=1$ to show that the closure of your set contains $C_c^\infty$.